# deployment Portable DB

Tags: database, qt, forms, deployment

How can i deploy a system that I can install in a PC and dont have to install a DBMS locally. I want the data repository of this system to sync with the main database online whenever the user want. The local system wont have internet access all the time. I could manage data locally with files or Access but I think a better solution must exist for this kind of problem.
What do you recommend me. I dont know if I explained my self well :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QSQLITE](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/sql-driver.html#qsqlite-for-sqlite-version-3-and-above).  SQLite is a very popular database that runs locally in-process without any required configuration.  QSQLITE is a plugin that provides a convenient QT-style API for it.

You will still have to write some kind of syncing/replication.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) exist with embedded version

> The embedded version is an amazing
>   variation of the server. It is a fully
>   featured Firebird server packed in
>   just a few files. It is very easy to
>   deploy, since there is no need to
>   install the server. It is ideal for
>   CDROM catalogs, demos or standalone
>   desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

See this [listing of candidates](http://bit.ly/9X8Exy) for your implementation.

: )

IMHO SQLLite will do the job.